# If $p,q,r$ are distinct primes such that $p<q<r$, then find all solutions to $p+q+r=pq$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I was solving another question, and was unable to solve the case written above. The question is as follows:

> If $p,q,r$ are distinct primes such that
> $$\frac{p^{3}+q^{3}+r^{3}}{p+q+r}=249$$then find all possible values of r

On using the identity $x^{3}+y^{3}+z^{3}-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}-xy-yz-xz)$, one can reduce the above question to the following,

> Find all distinct primes $p,q,r$ such that
> $$p+q+r|pqr$$

We have four cases for the following:

- $p+q+r=pqr$
- $p+q+r=qr$
- $p+q+r=pr$
- $p+q+r=pq$

I concluded that no solutions exist for the first three cases by assuming W.L.O.G, $p<q<r$. However, I am unable to do the same for the last case.

I request somebody to please provide a solution for this case or an alternate solution for the main question itself. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Not following your logic.  What happened to the $249$?  Are you claiming that the left hand can never be an integer?  But that doesn't sound true...taking $(p,q,r)=(3,7,11)$ we get $81$ on the left, just for example.  i note that in that case we have $p+q+r=21=pq$.

Comment: Should say, that phenomenon doesn't appear to be especially rare, at least for small primes.  Sticking just to triples of the form $(p_n,\,p_{n+2},\,p_{n+3})$ as in the example I gave, I find several with [minimal searching](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5B%28prime%5Bn%5D%5E3%2Bprime%5Bn%2B2%5D%5E3%2Bprime%5Bn%2B3%5D%5E3%29%2F%28prime%5Bn%5D%2Bprime%5Bn%2B2%5D%2Bprime%5Bn%2B3%5D%29%2C%7Bn%2C2%2C15%7D%5D)

Comment: $(3,11,19)$ is one solution.

Comment: Worth remarking that the left hand grows quite quickly in $r$ so a raw search should not be difficult.  To be precise, the numerator is greater than $r^3$ and the denominator is less than $3r$ so the left hand is greater than $\frac {r^2}3$.  It follows quickly that $r≤23$.

Comment: @lulu I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious but why is the numerator greater than $r^3$?

Comment: @Oussema  Because it is $r^3+q^3+p^3$ and the latter terms can not be negative.

Comment: @lulu Thanks. I was indeed missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are many solutions to $p+q+r = pq$. In particular, this can be rearranged to $r + 1 = (p-1)(q-1)$, so it is not unlikely to generate a pair $(p,q)$ from a prime $r$. In light of this, we should return the the given relation directly. WLOG suppose $p < q < r$. Then

$$249 = \frac {p^3+q^3+r^3}{p+q+r} > \frac {r^3}{3r} = \frac {r^2}{3}$$

This gives an upper bound: $r < \sqrt{744} < 28$. Hence $p<q<r\le23$.

Initially I listed the remainder of the cubes of these primes modulo $83$ (since $249 = 3\times 83$) and determined that $(3,11,19)$ is the only solution. [Warning: not fun]

However I believe that using your criterion $p+q+r=pq$, or $r+1 = (p-1)(q-1)$ would actually be simpler.

First note that $p \ne 2$: $2 + q + r = 2q \implies 2 +r = q$, which contradicts $r > q$.

Then, notice that $p < 5$: else $p \ge 5, q \ge 7, r = (p-1)(q-1)-1 \ge 23$. This gives the only case $(5,7,23)$, where $\dfrac {p^3+q^3+r^3}{p+q+r} = 361$. Hence we can only have $p=3$.

Since $r+1 = 2(q-1) \le 24$, we just need to check $q=5,7,11$, which gives $r = 7,11,19$, and $\dfrac {p^3+q^3+r^3}{p+q+r} = 33, 81, 249$. Hence $(3,11,19)$ is the only solution. Removing the WLOG, $r$ can take on all these values, so the required sum of possible values of $r$ is $33$.

Comment: $\frac{p^3+p^3+q^3}{p+q+r}$ at $(3,11,19)$ gives $\frac{1385}{33}$

Comment: @Raffaele: That is mathematically correct, but has no relevance to the problem at hand.